# How to make sure that installing Ubuntu on VMWare wont cause any losing data

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, windows-10, vmware

I want to run Ubuntu on VMWare so I have followed every steps properly but I have reached this step which makes me nervous about losing my own Windows 10 data:

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxt1s.png)

And as [this](https://youtu.be/9rUhGWijf9U?t=444) tutorial says, **Erase disk and install Ubuntu** option won't delete any data from Windows 10 and I should be selecting this option and press Next.

But the description of the option is a little bit scary which is saying:

```
This will delete your programs, ...
```

So what should I do now? I know this question is a little bit off-topic, but I do need to make sure that proceeding with this option won't damage any data of my Windows 10.

So please help me out this, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial is correct. The only thing Ubuntu knows inside VMWare is the virtual disk it is installed on.

Ubuntu *does not* have access to anything outside of VMWare, and can't touch any data on your Windows disk.

The description in the installer is made under the assumption that the OS is installed on a "real" disk and not on a virtual disk in a VM.